# Perforce p4v to share same changelist

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have 2 p4v set up on Windows and Linux. I was wondering if I can edit the code on Windows, create a pending changelist (this changelist belongs to a `p4_windows_client`). Then switch to Linux, which opens another `p4_linux_client`, to merge Windows pending changelist in order to build the project on Linux. The reason to have 2 different client {`p4_windows_client`, `p4_linux_client`} is because the root folder path issue as one is like `C:\p4clientRoot`, another is `/home/p4client-root`. I was wondering if this is possible?

I tested it, it seems like upon creating a pending changelist, the server will get that new changelist with only basic info, like change number, description, files being checked out. But it doesn't include the changes in the code being made on Windows box. So I feel it's unlikely to send over the change to Linux through this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *cannot* change the owner of the pending changelist changelist, however you can *shelve* the changelist in from **first workspace** and then *unshelve* it in the **second workspace**.

For more information check the Perforce Manual for the [`p4 shelve` command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/shelve.html) and [`p4 unshelve` command](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/unshelve.html).

Comment: To use shelving, you need have P4 2011.1 or later.

Comment: Shelving was introduced in 2009.2.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was earlier than 2011.1. I took 2011.1 from the linked documentation assuming that was the version the feature was available from.

Comment: You can change ownership of the shelved changelist as well by right-clicking the list and selecting `Change Ownership...`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have done dual development on windows and linux is to make 1 workspace, and use the "alt roots" line in your workspace. I make both my windows machine, and linux machine access the same share/drive. If it's dual boot, make a fat32 partition so both OS's can access the same drive, if they are 2 separate machines, create a network share on the machine you use most often, or on some network machine somewhere. Then make root and alt roots point to the same folder/share.

You also need to make sure that you blank out the Host line of the workspace so it can be used in both locations.

Now you can check out, edit, switch machines, and submit on the other machine.

Comment: What effect is there using a network drive for your workspace? Does it slow to sync/getlatest a large repository?

Comment: It all depends on your network speed. It would be as fast as copying that large repository to a mapped drive.